# Python with splinter library NameError: name 'Browser' is not defined

Tags: python, splinter

Code:

```py
from splinter import browser

with Browser('chrome') as browser:
    url = 'https://www.google.com/'
    browser.visit(url)
```

After running the module I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David Fahim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\webBrowser.py", line 3, in <module>
    with Browser('chrome') as browser:
NameError: name 'Browser' is not defined
```

I just ran the same code on repl.it and basically got the same error as before:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
        with Browser() as browser:
NameError: name 'Browser' is not defined
```

Comment: You imported `browser`, and then attempted to use `Browser`.  One of those has to be wrong...

Comment: @jasonharper I just changed it. Now I am getting: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable